# "A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier '' could not be found" error

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I am working on an app that I would like to put onto some iPads (not the App Store).  I bought the developer license, and added the provisions on Xcode.  Now when I try to build the app for the iPad which I have connected to my computer, I get the error:

`A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier '' could not be found`

I think that this problem has been caused because I have two different teams running on my Xcode, and I don't know how to specify the correct one (one has expired).  Also, I remember when I first created my App that I didn't really pay attention to the fields like 'Company Name', can I change those now?

---

EDIT:  Here are the provisions I do have:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very common (to me at least) error. It sounds like you just don't have a mobile provision for the app you're trying to put on your iPad. You need a .mobileprovision file for each app identifier. As for the various names of things, you can edit them in the info tab of your project or in info.plist.

If one of your profiles has expired then delete it, although this shouldn't affect anything.

To get a provision for your app, go to the apple provisioning portal and add a provisioning profile. Then you just have to put all of the specifications (UDID, development cert, application ID) in and it'll kick out a provision. There's a how-to guide on the apple developer site for both making provisions and putting them where they're supposed to be.

For some reason it also looks like your app's identifier is empty; you can change this in your project's info tab. The .mobileprovision app ID and your app's ID have to match EXACTLY otherwise nothing works.

Comment: How do I get the mobile provision?  (Sorry I am new at this).  I will also edit a screen shot into my question to show you what I do have.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue when i first installed the provisioning profile on the XCode. i'm using Xcode 4.5.* version. Although I installed the prov profile and certs in my mac, when i go to the Devices tab in the organizer in Xcode and clicked my device, i still couldn't see the new provisioning profile was added to the device. So I clicked the "Add to Portal" button with a + mark on it. It did the trick and i was able to test my app successfully without any errors about missing prov profile. Hope this helps for some of you with the issue i had.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to first BUILD the app with Cmd-B.

This popped up a keychain window access asking me to "Allow" (or "Always Allow") Xcode to access the keychain.

Only THEN could I actually run the program to launch it on my iPhone.

Apparently, hitting only run didn't do the trick.

(Btw, remember to first sign your app with the "iPhone Developer: Your Name ()" key.

Answer (score 0):

As Dustin said:

> The .mobileprovision app ID and your app's ID have to match EXACTLY
>   otherwise nothing works.

In your info.plist XCode automatically sets the 'Bundle identifier' to something like: 
com.domainname.applicationname${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}

Delete the '${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}' and leave only 'com.domainname.applicationname' so that it **exactly matches** your provisioning profile ID.

This worked for me when I had the same issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

This progress is a chaos. the hardest issue in the universe and the world I think.
it should be simple.
in xcode5 "fix issues" button doesn't fix issues. but hey ! this isnt take a day. but some hours to fix.