# Code signing error with sample app / new Provisioning Profile not in 'Code Signing' list

Tags: xcode

There are Code Signing Error issues on this forum but I couldnt find answer specific to my situation.
I have two issues really.

First issue:
 I'm getting a  "A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.yourcompany.thisSampleApp' could not be found" error.
I get this error running on the Device (iPhone 4S) for which I have a valid Provisioning Profile - com.mycompany.*. 
Since this didnt work, I created a Provisioning Profile for Bundle Identifier com.mycompany.thisSampleApp.
Same error.

Second issue:
I also noticed another thing, my newly created Provisional Profile does not show up in the 'Code Signing' section...so I cant even pick it.
But...I can see both the Provisional profiles listed in the Organizer window.

I downloaded Apple's Reachability sample Apple. Same error.

Any ideas anyone? Thanks!
PS: I'm running Xcode 4.6

Comment: possible duplicate of ["A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier '' could not be found" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745333/a-valid-provisioning-profile-matching-the-applications-identifier-could-not)

Answer (score 0):

when that happens to me, (and it happens a lot), I usually restart XCode, sometimes even the computer.  If you are sure you have the correct provisioning profile, and the correct certificates in your keychain, and you have the correct bundle identifier.

Also, go to the target -> Build Settings -> Code Signing, and re-select the correct one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This was for a sample application. It did have any certificate. But thanks.