# Check dependencies Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier

Tags: ios, xcode

I cant seem to solve this, its driving me crazy I've checked to see if everything matches. I have my provisions profile set correctly. I don't know if this matters but i have an old iPod 2nd generation set up and it says its not compatible with the version of Xcode I'm using. 
the full error message is

Check dependencies

Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.MyCompany.application' could not be found

Comment: Have you searched on this error message and looked at the many existing questions on the topic?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier '' could not be found" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745333/a-valid-provisioning-profile-matching-the-applications-identifier-could-not)